# a column with NULL's after every valid column in csv file, how to remove those columns and reload csv

Tags: csv, pyspark, null

here is an example csv data:

```
"ID", "name", "abbreviation", "CreatedTime", "CreatedByAccount", "UpdatedTime", "UpdatedByAccount", "inc_country_id", "time_zone_id"
"1","NULL","UNITED ARAB EMIRATES"",NULL","AE","NULL","2015-07-01 20:41:49","NULL","379","NULL","2016-03-16 07:38:49","NULL","8215","NULL","262","NULL","9","NULL"
```

this is causing column mismatch when iam trying create dataframe using pyspark
there are about 600+ such files which have above data, I need to read all these files with proper column mapping

```
>>> df=spark.read.csv("s3://xyz.csv",header=True)

>>> df.show()                                                                   
    +---+----+--------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
| ID|name|        abbreviation|CreatedTime|CreatedByAccount|UpdatedTime|   UpdatedByAccount|inc_country_id|time_zone_id|
+---+----+--------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
|  1|NULL|UNITED ARAB EMIRATES|       NULL|              AE|       NULL|2015-07-01 20:41:49|          NULL|         379|
|  2|NULL|           ARGENTINA|       NULL|              AR|       NULL|2015-07-01 20:41:49|          NULL|         379|
```

i tried an approach by creating a custom schema and read csv file, but this has to be done for 600 plus files with diff sizes and columns

```
>>> abc=StructType([StructField('ID',StringType(),True),StructField('c1',StringType(),True),StructField('name',StringType(),True),StructField('c2',StringType(),True),StructField('abbreviation',StringType(),True),StructField('c3',StringType(),True),StructField('CreatedTime',StringType(),True),StructField('c4',StringType(),True),StructField('CreatedByAccount',StringType(),True),StructField('c5',StringType(),True),StructField('UpdatedTime',StringType(),True),StructField('c6',StringType(),True),StructField('UpdatedByAccount',StringType(),True),StructField('c7',StringType(),True),StructField('inc_country_id',StringType(),True),StructField('c8',StringType(),True),StructField('time_zone_id',StringType(),True),StructField('c9',StringType(),True)])
>>> df=spark.read.csv("s3://xyz.csv/",schema=abc)
>>> df.show()
+---+----+--------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-------------------+--------------+----------------+----+-------------------+----+----------------+----+--------------+----+------------+----+
| ID|  c1|                name|         c2|    abbreviation|         c3|        CreatedTime|            c4|CreatedByAccount|  c5|        UpdatedTime|  c6|UpdatedByAccount|  c7|inc_country_id|  c8|time_zone_id|  c9|
+---+----+--------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-------------------+--------------+----------------+----+-------------------+----+----------------+----+--------------+----+------------+----+
|  1|NULL|UNITED ARAB EMIRATES|       NULL|              AE|       NULL|2015-07-01 20:41:49|          NULL|             379|NULL|2016-03-16 07:38:49|NULL|            8215|NULL|           262|NULL|           9|NULL|
|  2|NULL|           ARGENTINA|       NULL|              AR|       NULL|2015-07-01 20:41:49|          NULL|             379|NULL|2015-10-28 21:07:47|NULL|             379|NULL|           187|NULL|        None|NULL|
```

is there any generic way to reload all those files without NULL's using pyspark?

Comment: It seems that you are using comma-separator. Try spark.read.csv("my_csv.csv", header=True, sep=',')

Answer (score 0):

My solution is reading the file twice: one is for fetching schema (then manipulate it), and one is for actual reading

```py
# keep original fields so we can `select` later
df_schema = spark.read.csv('a.csv', header=True)
original_fields = df_schema.schema.fields

# adding extra dummy column after each valid column
expanded_fields = []
for i, field in enumerate(original_fields):
    expanded_fields.append(field)
    expanded_fields.append(T.StructField(f'col_{i}', T.StringType()))

# build a "fake" schema to fit with csv
schema = T.StructType(expanded_fields)

# using "fake" schema to load CSV, then select only valid columns from original fields
df = spark.read.csv('a.csv', header=True, schema=schema).select([field.name for field in original_fields])
df.show()
# +---+--------------------+------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------+------------+
# | ID|                name|abbreviation|        CreatedTime|CreatedByAccount|        UpdatedTime|UpdatedByAccount|inc_country_id|time_zone_id|
# +---+--------------------+------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------+------------+
# |  1|UNITED ARAB EMIRATES|          AE|2015-07-01 20:41:49|             379|2016-03-16 07:38:49|            8215|           262|           9|
# +---+--------------------+------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: yes @pltc went with same solution, thanks anyways